# Converting HEX values to Unicode characters

Tags: python, performance, serialization, unicode

I have a small bot for social network, which accepts message `"unicode XXXX XXXX XXXX ..."`, where `XXXX` - HEX values which I should convert to Unicode characters. Initially command accepted only one HEX value, and it worked fine and fast. After I modified code to accept multiple values, process slowed down (1-2 seconds response vs. 4-5 seconds).

Here is my code:

```
def unic(msg):
    if type(msg) == list:
        msg.pop(0) # removing "unicode" word
        try:
            sym = '' # final result
            correct = [] # correct HEX values to be converted
            for code in msg:
                try:
                    chr(int(code, 16))
                    correct.append(code)
                except:
                    pass
            if correct != []:
                for code in correct:
                    sym = sym + chr(int(code, 16))
            elif correct == []:
                return c_s.get('incorrect') # returning error message from common strings list
            if sym != '':
                return sym
        except:
            return c_s.get('incorrect')
```

What should I change here to accelerate process? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Note that 'hex' is short for 'hexadecimal' — there's no reason to write it in capital letters.

Comment: That's a _hugely_ greater time difference than I'd expect from simple algorithmic code (no database lookups, etc.). I suspect the extra time is mostly your system having to load and render uncached parts of a font.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only use `try`-`except` when you need to. Your outer try *should* be useless.
You should also perform `chr(int(code, 16))` once, as there is no gain to running it twice, it just costs cycles.

Your output is horrible, if there is no valid input you go from explicitly silencing it to *returning* an error.
And if somehow you have an array of items, but they don't get added to `sym` you return `None`.
You need to pick how your function works. Either remove invalid characters, or raise errors.

Doing the above removes half your code. I'd also change `except` to catch certain errors, e.g. `ValueError`, otherwise your program is prone to mask bugs.

Strings are immutable and so `sym = sym + chr(int(code, 16))` can take a very long amount of time.
Instead build a list and `''.join` it.

Finally `return c_s.get('incorrect')` is a massive red flag, remove these and `raise` exceptions instead.

This can get you:

```
def unicode_(msg):
    new_msg = []
    for char in msg:
        try:
            char = chr(int(char, 16))
        except ValueError:
            char = '?'
        new_msg.append(char)
    return ''.join(new_msg)
```

Comment: @MaxLunar No problem! Just so you know accepting my answer so early discourages others to post answers, and you may miss out on a better answer than the one I provided. :)

Comment: That code already looks fine, and I have tested it in work. It does work as fast as single HEX value converter.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it can sometimes take a little while" — more than half a microsecond?

Comment: @deltab What did you try? I tried `abcd`, and it took half a second.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Did you also output the character? It's a CJK character and if you haven't rendered any CJK characters recently, your system would have to load uncached parts of a font file. Try doing it again and compare how long it takes each time.

Comment: @deltab I'll fix it when I next get a chance